# Move Load balancer certificate to another AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balance

I have two AWS accounts. Created a load balancer on "first" account, requested a certificate and using it for HTTPS.

Now I need to move this load balancer certificate to "second" account because it is requested for the same domain I need to use.

What is the procedure to do this.

1. Delete certificate from first aws and request again from
   the second aws?
2. Is there any way to export the certificate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to delete it from the first account. AWS will issue certificates as long as you can prove domain ownership. Nothing stopping you from having a cert for the same domain in multiple accounts.